# Includes: 'date' .php

Tags: php, include

I want a include in my sidebar.
With everyday another page, I make the page, and name it (IE. 0311.php, 0411.php), and the include automaticly changes the date (just the simple php dates).

Hope you get it! Thanks

Comment: I get it. Now what is your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably one of the worst formated questions I cared to answer.

```
include date("md").".php";
```

Comment: So badly formatted in fact, that you forgot to quote your date argument. ;-)

Comment: @netcoder so badly formatted that I should have done it on purpose! ;) (thks)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php require_once date("dm") . ".php"; ?>
```